# Flag creation on record

Tags: formula

I need to generate a yellow flag on a record when the field "Flag_Reason__c" (text field) is not blank.

Can someone point me in the correct direction, this is what I have so far.

```
IF(
NOT(
ISBLANK(Flag_Reason__c),
IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif", Null)))
```

And I am getting this error

> Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error says, you are missing a parenthesis (and the else clause). Your formula should be this way:

```
IF(
   NOT(ISBLANK(Flag_Reason__c)),
   IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif", ""),
   ""
)
```

Comment: thanks Sebastian. For the life of me I could not see it.

Comment: All good. Please feel free to mark the question as accepted so others can benefit from your experience